# Problem in generating Key Pairs with cryptography.hazmat library in python

Tags: python, json, cryptography, rsa, key-pair

I am trying to generate a key pair in python using the cryptography.hazmat library ... like presented in the screen shot :

[image: Pthon code to generate Key pair]

but the out put keys when added to a json object the got w wrong format ... i got an "\n" added and the key isn't good like this ...

[image: output keys]

I already tried Translate, Replace, JSONDecoder ... without getting a good output 
Who can help in resolving this please ... and thank you

Comment: output1.replace('\n ', '')

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Post the text of it and then use the code formatting features.